# How do I pass the BuildStringArray in response here

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am able to connect to the MySQL database and get the data , However the when I put the data in a array it shows zero outside the function

New Node.js user trying use mysqlx@xdevapi . I want to get the resultset of the query and pass it to the request . But currently its showing 0

```
router.get('/getBuilds', function(req, res) {
            count = 0;
            var BuildStringArray = [];
            mysqlx.getSession({
                user: 'myuser',
                password: 'mypssword',
                host: 'localhost',
                port: '33060'
            }).then(function(s) {
                session = s
                return session.getSchema('test')
            }).then(function() {
                return Promise.all([
                    session.sql('USE test').execute(),
                    session.sql('SELECT BuildS FROM Builds;').execute(function(result) {
                        console.log(count++ + " : " + result); // prints 64 rows of data
                        BuildStringArray.push(result);
                    })
                ])

            })..then(result => {
                res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
                res.status(200).json(result);
                session.close();
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
                res.status(500).send({
                    message: "${err}"
                })
                session.close();
            });
```

I want to gather the BuildStringArray then pass that to the response

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing the row data into this `BuildStringArray` array but you are returning back the data to which `Promise.all()` resolves (which in this case just contains some metadata about the operations).

```
.then(result => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  res.status(200).json(result);
  session.close();
})
```

I believe changing it to `json(BuildStringArray)` would do the trick. However, I would also be careful with the async flow inside that `express` (I assume) controller. Unless you are using some bleeding-edge version with support for `Promise`s and/or `async/await`, that might need some additional supervision. Also, bear in mind that `session.close()` is async as well, so you will also benefit from prefixing it with a `return` in that case.

Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer of the MySQL Node.js X DevAPI connector.